# Changed background color for network drives

Tags: colors, total-commander

Is it possible to change background color (or font color) when viewing network drives? My computer would be white (regular) and the network drivers would be different color?

Edit: Using total commander for Windows 7 in a strictly windows based network.

Comment: You need to give more information on your environment, like what operating system or desktop environment you are using. Without such information your question is not answerable.

Comment: You should only change the system font, if you are in one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your desire is inspired by the option "Define color by file types", but there is no chance to define a conditional color scheme for network drives. You can only define a common color scheme for all drives.

You could submit a suggestion at the [Total Commander Forum](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/index.php?language=english).